# react - how to pass event from another class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom-events

### What I have

I have a class that's not being exported but being used internally by a file. (The classes are all in the same file)

```
class SearchResults extends Component {
  constructor()
  {
      super();
      this.fill_name = this.fill_name.bind(this);
  }

  fill_name(event, name)
  {
      console.log("search results", event.target);
      this.props.fill_name(name, event.target);
  }

  render()
  {
      return (
          <div className="search-results-item" onClick={ () => this.fill_name(event, this.props.name)}>
              <div className="highlight">
                  {this.props.name}
              </div>
          </div>
      )
  }
}
```

I'm trying to get the `<div>` element to be sent back to the parent, which is defined below (skipping irrelevant stuff):

```
class PublishComponent extends Component {
  fill_name(name, me)
  {
      console.log(me);
      $("#company_input").val(name);
      this.setState({ list: { ...this.state.list, company: [] } });
  }
}
```

`me` is the event.

### What I'm getting

The console posts the following:

```
search results <react>​</react>​
undefined
```

so the event.target is `<react></react>` for some reason, while the `me` is getting undefined.

### Expected behaviour

It should return the element i.e. `<div className="search-results-item"...></div>`

Comment: I'd need to see more of your code, but it feels like you should be able to avoid using jQuery to manipulate the `#company_input` element. It's also not clear why you need to pass the div in the first place. This feels wrong - there should be a way to do things without directly working with the DOM.

Comment: @Michael It's actually quite dynamic now, and I need to get it relative to what I'm clicking on, so instead of `$("#company_input").val(name);` it's now `let parent_val = $(me).parent().prev(); $(parent_val).val(name);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not passing the `event` object

Change This

```
<div
  className="search-results-item"
  onClick={() => this.fill_name(event, this.props.name)}
/>
```

To This

```
<div
  className="search-results-item"
  // pass the event here
  onClick={event => this.fill_name(event, this.props.name)}
/>
```

Comment: marking in 6 mins. Strange, because I have other event stuff and I don't call them like that.

Comment: Can you show how you use them? we can discuss how/why they are working/not working!

Comment: Ah, they're working, but it might be because they're implicitly passed. So I don't have any variables passed to them.

Comment: Yes, and that is the better way to do it:: `onClick={this.fill_name}`, because when you do like this:: `onClick={(e) => this.fillname(e)}` the function will be created every time the `render` function is invoked, and judging from your code, you can avoid that!

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
class SearchResults extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.fill_name = this.fill_name.bind(this);
  }

  fill_name() {
    this.props.fill_name(this.props.name, this.ref)
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="search-results-item" ref={ref => { this.ref = ref }} onClick={this.fill_name}>
        <div className="highlight">
          {this.props.name}
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```